# To customize Google Calendar Embed in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am new in **WordPress**. I have installed **Google Calendar embed**. I made a **JQuery** file because I want to customize the page.

**CASE:** When five seconds are spent, I need to change several colors in the web page.

I have got it working partially, although I can't customize the Google Calendar part of the code, I feel like I haven't any control of that part of the code.

**My JQuery file have this code :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('div#main').css({'background' : 'blue'});
        $('h3.widget-title').css({'color' : 'olive'});
        $('img.subscribe-image').css({'width' : '400px'});
        $('aside#archives-3.widget.widget_archive').css({'width' : '900px' , 'heihgt' : '1200px' , 'float' : 'left' , 'margin-left' : '-500px'});
    }, 3000);

});
```

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use CSS?

Comment: I don't think that's possible since google calendar is in an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like the plugin is making an **iframe** from google calendar. Checkout the source code of your page, if it is indeed an iframe then you cant change any parameters in it. Its for security reason so no one can modify a page to look like someone else's page. The best bet would be to use **google calendar's api** and change the colors.

If its not an iframe then your code is correct, it should be able to change the css. **Try replacing $ with jQuery**, just to avoid any conflicts.